# How can I send a string in a function

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this code and I want to make it send "b1" when when executing the command mic_press `b1 = Button(root, image= img1, bd=0, bg='#292424', activebackground='#292424', command=mic_press)`

Comment: What do you mean "send"?  Send where?  Also, do you want _this_ code to send, or do you want the `mic_press` function to send?

Comment: It seems that what is meant is to "send" the string `"b1"` "to" `mic_press` itself - i.e., to *pass* it *as an argument*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you want

```py
b1 = Button(root, image= img1, bd=0, bg='#292424', activebackground='#292424', command=lambda:mic_press('b1'))
```

Tkinter commands take and pass no arguments, but you can use a `lambda` function to call your method with the desired value(s)